# Print in .NET - Conversion from millimeter to pixel

Tags: c#, printing

How can I convert user input from millimeter to pixels so that it's printed on the right position of the page?

I use the following code:

```
private void document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    float dpiX = e.Graphics.DpiX;
    float dpiY = e.Graphics.DpiY;
    Point p = new Point(mmToPixel(float.Parse(edtBorderLeft.Text), dpiX), 
            mmToPixel(float.Parse(edtBorderTop.Text), dpiY));
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(testImage, p);

}

private int mmToPixel(float mm, float dpi)
{
    return (int)Math.Round((mm / 25.4)  * dpi);
}
```

edtBorderLeft.Text got the value of "9.5" and edtBorderTop.Text the value of "21,5". These values are millimeters. If I check the output with this code:

```
    private void printPage()
    {
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
        dialog.Document = document;
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PrintPreviewDialog preview = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            preview.Document = document;
            preview.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            preview.Show();
            //document.Print();
        }            
    }
```

It displays the image nearly in the center of the page. A calculation example:

mmToPixel(float.Parse(edtBorderLeft.Text), dpiX)
edtBorderLeft.Text = "9.5"
dpiX = 600;
returns: 224

How can I calculate the right point for the printed image?

Comment: would you try the TextRender.MeasureText(); and see if that can do something in this case

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found another solution. Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution. You can change the page unit with the following code. So I don't need a conversion:

```
 e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
```

or

```
e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
```

and I can use the code above.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a little explanation. By default Graphics.PageUhit is set to "Display". For a screen display this usually means 96 pixels per inch, for a printer it is 100 dots per inch. This info is buried in MSDN somehwere but is hard to find.

Therefore for a printer, instead of using dpiX/dpiY you could assume a value of 100, but it is probably safer to set the units to millimeters.