# Define Label size in Millimeters but create image in pixels

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to build an app to print Barcode labels by using GDPicture library. The task user can define label (paper size) in millimeters.

But in code i must create an image (with GDPicture) width and height should be defined in pixels.

For example if label real size is 51*28 in C# code

```
        //convert mm to inches
        double iWidth = labelContainerWidth / 25.4;
        double iHeight = labelContainerHeight / 25.4;
        double dpiX = ps.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X;
        double dpiY = ps.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Y;
        result[0] = iWidth * dpiX;
        result[1] = iHeight * dpiY;
        return result;
```

602*330 in pixels
Of course it is a too big for this paper..

PS: I know i can get default paper size by:

```
 double w = ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width/100.0;
 double h = ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height/100.0;
```

What else should i add or devide also?

Comment: What you print on paper gets rescaled by the Graphics.PageUnit.  Default is "display", produces 100 pixels per inch.  How this relates to what that library does or whether you use a standard PrinterController is not obvious.  Consider using a ruler.

Comment: [Print in .NET - Conversion from millimeter to pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722809/print-in-net-conversion-from-millimeter-to-pixel), [Graphics.TransformPoints - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fsfk76a.aspx)

Comment: @HansPassant With the library im not able to change Unit

Comment: @HansPassant I have tried to devide 100 but then 18 digit barcode number doesn't fit